# Does such a collection exist (functionality from Dictionary & HashSet)?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, collections, hashset

I am looking for a collection where no element can exist more than once, and are also indexed. Similar to `Dictionary`, but without Key, just Value. Similar to a `HashSet`, but indexed so I can easily retrieve an element without iterating over the collection. I hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: Depends on your definition of "Indexed", can you go in to more detail of how you would use said index?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashSet`. It is "indexed", after all, performance would be lacking if it weren't.

Use the [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to "retrieve" an element. If you want to remove it as well, use [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342694(v=vs.110).aspx).

Both methods are O(1) operations.

Comment: Doesn't help if you want to retrieve the actual object present in the hash set, given another object equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<T, T>` for that and insert elements using `Add(value, value)`.

However, that only makes sense if your type properly implements `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`. If it doesn't, two different instanced will never be equal and the `HashSet<T>`'s `Contains(T)` method already tells you whether you have the element reference of nor.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet class is best for your work. I won't allow duplicate entries.
Note that the HashSet.Add(T item) method returns a **bool -- true** if the item was added to the collection; **false** if the item was already present.

Simply you can add an Extension method to throw exception as

```
 public static void AddOrThrow<T>(this HashSet<T> hash, T item)
    {
        if (!hash.Add(item))
            throw new ValueExistingException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is make a class that implements `IList<T>` but uses a `List<T>` and `HashSet<T>` internally. You then just have each method act on each collection as needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Example
{
    public class UniqueList<T> : IList<T>
    {
        private readonly List<T> _list;
        private readonly HashSet<T> _hashset;

        public UniqueList()
        {
            _list = new List<T>();
            _hashset = new HashSet<T>();
        }

        public UniqueList(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            _list = new List<T>();
            _hashset = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
        }

        void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
        {
            Add(item);
        }

        public bool Add(T item)
        {
            var added = _hashset.Add(item);
            if (added)
            {
                _list.Add(item);
            }
            return added;
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _hashset.Remove(_list[index]);
            _list.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public T this[int index]
        {
            get { return _list[index]; }
            set
            {
                var oldItem = _list[index];
                _hashset.Remove(oldItem);
                var added = _hashset.Add(value);
                if (added)
                {
                    _list[index] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Put the old item back before we raise a exception.
                    _hashset.Add(oldItem);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Object already exists.");
                }
            }
        }

        public int IndexOf(T item)
        {
            return _list.IndexOf(item);
        }

        void IList<T>.Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            Insert(index, item);
        }

        public bool Insert(int index, T item)
        {
            var added = _hashset.Add(item);
            if (added)
            {
                _list.Insert(index, item);
            }
            return added;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _list.Clear();
            _hashset.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            return _hashset.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            var removed = _hashset.Remove(item);
            if (removed)
            {
                _list.Remove(item);
            }
            return removed;
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _list.Count; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _list.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

    }
}
```

I did explicit implementations of `Add` and `Insert` so I could give them versions that returned a `bool` to tell if the operation succeeded or not. I could not return a value in the `T this[int index]` setter so I have it throw a `InvalidOperationException` if you attempt to insert a duplicate.

It does not throw if you do `ICollection.Add` on a duplicate, it just does not add it. This is because that is the behavior `HashSet<T>.ICollection<T>.Add` has and i wanted to mimic it.